# Error messages with Traminer seqtree and seqtreedisplay

Tags: r, traminer

I am using newly updated R and Traminer on a Mac to analyze sequence data and am having trouble getting seqtree and seqtreedisplay to run regression trees.  Using the biofam data that comes with TraMineR, R gives three error messages with simple trees and regression trees.

```
library(TraMineR)
library(TraMineRextras)

data(biofam)
bio.seq <- seqdef(biofam, 10:25, weights=bio$wp00tbgs, xtstep = 2)

## Create Ward clusters using an OM distance matrix

properties <- matrix(c(# left, married, child, divorced
  0, 0, 0, 0, # parent
  1, 0, 0, 0, # left
  0, 1, .5, 0,# married
  1, 1, 0, 0, # left+married
  0, 0, 1, 0, # child
  1, 0, 1, 0, # left+child
  1, 1, 1, 0, # left+married+child
  .5, 1, .5, 1 #divorced
), 8, 4, byrow=TRUE)

sm <- as.matrix(dist(properties))
indel <- .5 * max(sm)
bio.dist <- seqdist(bio.seq, method="OM", indel=indel, sm=sm, full.matrix=FALSE)

weight <- attr(bio.seq, "weights")
ward <- hclust(bio.dist, method="ward", members=weight)

## Tree display of the cluster solution and growing a regression tree

tree2 <- as.seqtree(ward, seqdata=bio.seq, diss=bio.dist, ncluster=2)
seqtreedisplay(tree2, type="I", border=NA, sortv="from.start", showdepth=TRUE) 

treereg <- seqtree(bio.seq ~ sex + plingu02, data=biofam, 
               diss=bio.dist)
seqtreedisplay(treereg, type="I", border=NA, sortv="from.start")
```

The error messages are

```
> seqtreedisplay(tree2, type="I", border=NA, sortv="from.start", showdepth=TRUE)
sh: dot: command not found
The file /private/var/folders/YY/YYp18zjXELKZUAbIpHvtIk+++TI/-Tmp-
/RtmpVNNMlt/tmpseqtree3745b091371.png does not exist.

> treereg <- seqtree(bio.seq ~ sex + cohort2 + religion + plingu02, data=bio,
 diss=bio.dist)
Error in DTNdisstree(dissmatrix = dissmatrix, predictor = predictor, terms = tterms,  : 
[!] To permute replicate, you should specify integer weights

> seqtreedisplay(treereg, type="I", border=NA, sortv="from.start")
Error in inherits(seqdata, "stslist") : object 'treereg' not found
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the following errors:

- `as.seqtree` is provided by the `WeightedCluster` package (so you need to load it with `library(WeightedCluster)`).
- You need to install GraphViz for `seqtreedisplay` to work correctly:  see http://www.graphviz.org/ (you will need to restart R after installing GraphViz)
- Since your sequence object is weighted, you need to specify how weights should be permuted (usually, we use `weight.permutation = "diss"` to permute the distance matrix).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you.  Both of the trees run with these modifications.